# How to sort mongo query result stored in cursor using java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using java and mongo db.
I have stored multple documents in mongodb. I want to fetch only 12 documents whose timestamp is less than timestamp provided to query.

The condition is that query must select 12 documents whose timestamp is closer to given timestamp.

Here is what I did??

```
BasicDBObject criteria = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject projections = new BasicDBObject();
criteria.put("hostId",ip);
criteria.put("status",0);
projections.put("runtimeMillis",1);
projections.put("cpuUtilization",1);
String json_string="";
DBCursor cur = coll.find(criteria,projections).sort(new BasicDBObject("runtimeMillis",-1)).limit(12);

Object[] row = createOutputRow(new Object[0], outputRowSize);
int index = 0;
String mystring = null;
List list = new ArrayList();
JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
json_string = "[";

 while(cur.hasNext() && !isStopped()) {
    String json = cur.next().toString(); 
    JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(json);
    long convert = Long.parseLong(responseObject.getString("runtimeMillis"));
    long set_date =  convert;
    Date dateObj = new Date(set_date);
    String date_text = ft.format(dateObj);

int month = 0;
month = Integer.parseInt(new  java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(dateObj));
    /json_string +="{x:  ("+convert+"),y: "+responseObject.getString("cpuUtilization")+", color: \"red\"},";
  }//end of while
```

This gives me correct output but in descending order.
If I sort documents in ascending order, I got oldest documents.

I want output in ascending order and must be closer to given timestamp(latest documents whose timestamp is less than given timestamp) and are sorted in ascending order.

How do I get this result??

Comment: I might help to look at some [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) For to have produced the code you have without understanding the usage of sort it can only be copied code. Some reading would help you. The standard documentation is not hard to apply to the Java methods.

Answer (score 0):

Let me check I understand correctly what you're trying to do.  You're looking for the 12 documents with timestamps *just before* a given time?  So, for example, if you had the following data set (I'm using very simplified timestamps for ease of understanding):

```
{ documentNumber: 1, timestamp: 1002 },
{ documentNumber: 2, timestamp: 1003 },
{ documentNumber: 3, timestamp: 1005 },
{ documentNumber: 4, timestamp: 1007 },
{ documentNumber: 5, timestamp: 10011 },
{ documentNumber: 6, timestamp: 10013 },
{ documentNumber: 7, timestamp: 10017 },
{ documentNumber: 8, timestamp: 10019 },
{ documentNumber: 9, timestamp: 10023 },
{ documentNumber: 10,timestamp: 10031 },
{ documentNumber: 11,timestamp: 10037 },
{ documentNumber: 12,timestamp: 10041 },
{ documentNumber: 13,timestamp: 10053 },
{ documentNumber: 14,timestamp: 10057 },
{ documentNumber: 15,timestamp: 10063 },
{ documentNumber: 16,timestamp: 10065 },
{ documentNumber: 17,timestamp: 10069 },
{ documentNumber: 18,timestamp: 10074 },
{ documentNumber: 19,timestamp: 10079 }
```

and you searched for the timestamp 10069, you want to find the 12 documents just before that timestamp, but in ascending order.  So you want to get documents 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16?

Your current code is enormously over-complicated, which is why there's the comment suggesting you check the documentation.  However, you're actually partially correct, you can't order it in ascending order *and* get the values that you want.

I'm not at all sure what your code on the lines after `DBCursor cur = ...` are for, that messing around with JSON and Dates and stuff looks pretty hairy, and there are simpler ways to do that, but I'll leave you to research that.  However, I have written something that should give you more or less what you need, in terms of the query, and I've written a test to prove that this does what you want:

```
@Test
public void shouldUseASortForLimitCriteriaAndSortArrayInPlace() {
    // given 
    long timestampStartingPoint = 1000;
    for (long timestamp = timestampStartingPoint; timestamp < 1100; timestamp++) {
        //insert some basic documents into the database with different timestamps
        collection.insert(new BasicDBObject("timestamp", timestamp));
    }

    // when
    long timestampToSearchFor = 1050; // halfway through the data set
    // this is the query for documents older than a chosen timestamp
    BasicDBObject queryForDocumentsOlderThanTimestampToSearchFor = new BasicDBObject("timestamp", new BasicDBObject("$lt", timestampToSearchFor));

    // limit selects only 12, you have to sort descending to get the 12 closes to the selected timestamp 
    List<DBObject> foundItems = collection.find(queryForDocumentsOlderThanTimestampToSearchFor)
                                          .limit(12)
                                          .sort(new BasicDBObject("timestamp", -1))
                                          .toArray();
    // now you have to sort the returned array into the order you want
    Collections.sort(foundItems, new Comparator<DBObject>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final DBObject o1, final DBObject o2) {
            return (int) ((Long) o1.get("timestamp") - (Long) o2.get("timestamp"));
        }
    });

    // then
    assertThat(foundItems.size(), is(12));
    assertThat((Long) foundItems.get(0).get("timestamp"), is(1038L));
    assertThat((Long) foundItems.get(11).get("timestamp"), is(1049L));
}
```

Note that this solution is OK in your case because you're *only* returning 12 items.  If the results are very large, this may *not* work as the whole list will be in memory. That's why it's usually better to do sorting in the database.

There is another way to achieve this, using the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) - that will let you set up one sort to use for the limit (you need to sort descending to limit to the correct 12 items) and a second sort to put them into the order you want.

The key points to understand in my solution are:

- [$lt](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/), to get the timestamps older than a given value
- [limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) to return only a subset of results
- [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) and [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for sorting an array in Java

I also recommend you check out the documentation for [Aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/).